# is there is a way to show old date and time picker in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uidatepicker

I am new in swift and I am facing problem with new date picker
I need to show old date piker

[image]

But the current date piker is like this

[image]

Is there is any way to show old picker

My code is like this

```
func showDatePickerFrom(){
        //Formate Date
        let date = Date()
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        let result = formatter.string(from: date)
        let dateToday = formatter.date(from: result)
        
        FromdatePicker.datePickerMode = .date
        FromdatePicker.maximumDate = dateToday
        //ToolBar
        let toolbar = UIToolbar();
        toolbar.sizeToFit()
        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(donedatePicker))
        let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(cancelDatePicker))
        toolbar.setItems([cancelButton,spaceButton,doneButton], animated: false)
        txtdateselect.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
        txtdateselect.inputView = FromdatePicker
        
    }
    
    @objc func donedatePicker(){
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
        txtdateselect.text = formatter.string(from: FromdatePicker.date)
        self.view.endEditing(true)   
    }
    
    @objc func cancelDatePicker(){
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
```

Comment: Try changing the `preferredDatePickerStyle` to wheels. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatepicker/3526124-preferreddatepickerstyle

Comment: @ShawnFrank Its shows it only available in iOS 13.4 or newer

Comment: @Muju: Yes, old will show like picker only. From 13.4, Apple change the way it show picker. to show date as picker, make change as Shawn suggested....

Comment: @FahimParkar Got it

Comment: @Muju : Accept the answer if it helped. Also check what I have mentioned in Note as that is very important...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From iOS 13.4, Apple change the way it show picker.

To show date picker in old way, just add below lines in the code.

```
if #available(iOS 13.4, *) {
    self.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
}
```

***Note*** : *You have to write this line right after you initialize date picker.*

E.x. If you write this line after setting maximum or minimum date, it won't work like below.

```
if #available(iOS 13.4, *) {
    self.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
}

self.minimumDate = Date()
```